# Are there any roleplaying guidelines for Science Talk

Tags: roleplaying, science-fiction, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

I'm going to try my best with roleplaying a crazy Scientist. However I have got a problem with 'Science talk'. I was wondering, are there any techniques or guidelines for nerd/technical talk, which does not irritate other players, or sound just too cheesy (when used by someone who does not have so much technical knowledge)?

We are a small group which will create a rebel cell.  My character is a  scientist (chemist and physicist) previously working for the Empire. 
Unappreciated by the Empire because of his race he joined the Rebels.  He thinks that the Empire should regret ever doubting his genius.

Comment: This might be a useful read: [How do I technobabble without sounding like technobabble?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90927/how-do-i-technobabble-without-sounding-like-technobabble)

Comment: @PurpleMonkey possibly even a dup?

Comment: The answer's really going to vary with the technical proficiency of you and your group, so that information may be useful in the question statement.

Comment: @Wibbs possibly but to me the "dup" question seems to be "how do I explain 'technobabble' in layman's terms" while this one seems more "how do I technobabble".

Comment: What makes the linked question not answer your own? As I'm reading your question now, it sounds like a duplicate. Can you edit what sets your question apart? The recent edit of the background didn't help much.